# How to initialize a Dictionary with structure components in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, initialization, structure

I have the following structure:

```
struct song {
var songnum: Int = 0
var name = "not defined"
var lyrics_wo_chords = NSMutableAttributedString()
var lyrics_w_chords = NSMutableAttributedString()
var favorite = false
}
```

And I'm trying to make a dictionary `var songs = [String: [song]]()`

where the the `String` is the name of the Songbook and the `[song]`
is an array of structures called song that hold the individual structure members

I've tried this `songs["SongBook name"] = song.self as? [song]` to add a new Key to the Dictionary. But otherwise, i have no idea how i would initialize it.

Also, when i append the array of the Key:

```
songs["SongBook name"]?.append(song(
songnum: 1, 
name: "Name", 
lyrics_o_chords: NSMutableAttributedString(string:"No Chords"), 
lyrics_w_chords: NSMutableAttributedString(string: "With Chords"), 
favorite: 
false))`
```

the dictionary returned is nil

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value in your dictionary is an array of `song` (that is `[song]`), so you need to put `[` `]` around your value to make it into an array of `song`:

```
songs["SongBook name"] = [song(
    songnum: 1,
    name: "Name",
    lyrics_wo_chords: NSMutableAttributedString(string:"No Chords"),
    lyrics_w_chords: NSMutableAttributedString(string: "With Chords"),
    favorite: false)
]
```

Structure and class names should be capitalized, so use `Song` instead of `song` when defining your structure.

Comment: thank you, the issue was that the Key "SongBook Name" had to be initialized once with the first element, after, the array was appended for each new song.